# Auto submit a form when $_POST vars hit the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Hello stackexchange community,

I'm trying to use a node.js script to pass post variables onto a php page where when the post vars generate the page the page auto submits using document.getElementById('form1').click();

I know that the php is working because in my terminal i can see all the values prepopulating. But my javascript won't auto-submit the form to the other page.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
<?php

$firstname = (isset($_POST['firstname']))?$_POST['firstname']:'';
$lastname = (isset($_POST['lastname']))?$_POST['lastname']:'';
$address1 =(isset($_POST['address1']))? $_POST['address1']:'';
$city =(isset($_POST['city']))? $_POST['city']:'';
$state = (isset($_POST['state']))?$_POST['state']:'';
$zip = (isset($_POST['zip']))?$_POST['zip']:'';
$phone =(isset($_POST['phone1']))? $_POST['phone1']:'';
$email =(isset($_POST['email']))? $_POST['email']:'';
$ApptDate = (isset($_POST['ApptDate']))?$_POST['ApptDate']:'';
$ApptTime = (isset($_POST['ApptTime']))?$_POST['ApptTime']:'';
$notes = (isset($_POST['notes']))?$_POST['notes']:'';
$sender = (isset($_POST['sender']))?$_POST['sender']:'';

?>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['firstname']))
{?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form name='form1' id='form1' action='http://hg06.leadperfection.com/batch/addleads.asp' method='POST'>
   <table border=1 cellspacing=0 callpadding=0>
   <tr><td>FirstName</td><td><input type='Text' id='firstname' name='firstname' maxlength='25' value="<?php echo $firstname;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>LastName</td><td><input type='Text' id='lastname' name='lastname' maxlength='25' value="<?php echo $lastname;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Address1</td><td><input type='Text' id='address1' name='address1' maxlength='35' value="<?php echo $address1;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>City</td><td><input type='Text' id='city' name='city' maxlength='35' value="<?php echo $city;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>State</td><td><input type='Text' id='state' name='state' maxlength='2' value="<?php echo $state;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Zip</td><td><input type='Text' id='zip' name='zip' maxlength='15' value="<?php echo $zip;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone1</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone1' name='phone1' maxlength='15' value="<?php echo $phone1;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone2</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone2' name='phone2' maxlength='15' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone2Type</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone2type' name='phone2type' maxlength='2' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone3</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone3' name='phone3' maxlength='15' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone3Type</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone3type' name='phone3type' maxlength='2' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Product</td><td><input type='Text' id='productid' name='productid' maxlength='10' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>ProdDescr</td><td><input type='Text' id='proddescr' name='proddescr' maxlength='20' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type='Text' id='email' name='email' maxlength='100' value="<?php echo $email;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>LogNumber</td><td><input type='Text' id='LogNumber' name='LogNumber' maxlength='50' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Sender</td><td><input type='Text' id='sender' name='sender' maxlength='100' value="<?php echo $sender;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Sent To</td><td><input type='Text' id='sentto' name='sentto' maxlength='100' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Call Morning (Y/N)</td><td><input type='Text' id='callmorning' name='callmorning' maxlength='1' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Call Afternoon (Y/N)</td><td><input type='Text' id='callafternoon' name='callafternoon' maxlength='1' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Call Weekend (Y/N)</td><td><input type='Text' id='callevening' name='callevening' maxlength='1' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Call Evening (Y/N)</td><td><input type='Text' id='callweekend' name=callweekend' maxlength='1' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>ApptDate</td><td><input type='Text' id='ApptDate' name='ApptDate' maxlength='20' value="<?php echo $ApptDate;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>ApptTime</td><td><input type='Text' id='ApptTime' name='ApptTime' maxlength='20' value="<?php echo $ApptTime;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>ProID</td><td><input type='Text' id='ProID' name='ProID' maxlength='5' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Srs-Sub ID#</td><td><input type='Text' id='srs_id' name='srs_id' maxlength='5' value="<?php echo $first;  ?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Notes</td><td><input type='Text' id='notes' name='notes' maxlength='2000' value="<?php echo $notes;  ?>"></td></tr>
   </table>
   <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>document.getElementById('form1').click();</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
  // leave the page alone
}
?>
```

Here is my terminal output confirming that post variable are in fact hitting the page. As you can see value is populated and the page generated according to the php.

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form name='form1' id='form1' action='http://hg06.leadperfection.com/batch/addleads.asp' method='POST'>
   <table border=1 cellspacing=0 callpadding=0>
   <tr><td>FirstName</td><td><input type='Text' id='firstname' name='firstname' maxlength='25' value="alan"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>LastName</td><td><input type='Text' id='lastname' name='lastname' maxlength='25' value="huber"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Address1</td><td><input type='Text' id='address1' name='address1' maxlength='35' value="east 123 hello st"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>City</td><td><input type='Text' id='city' name='city' maxlength='35' value="roscoe"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>State</td><td><input type='Text' id='state' name='state' maxlength='2' value="IL"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Zip</td><td><input type='Text' id='zip' name='zip' maxlength='15' value="61073"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone1</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone1' name='phone1' maxlength='15' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone2</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone2' name='phone2' maxlength='15' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone2Type</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone2type' name='phone2type' maxlength='2' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone3</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone3' name='phone3' maxlength='15' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Phone3Type</td><td><input type='Text' id='phone3type' name='phone3type' maxlength='2' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Product</td><td><input type='Text' id='productid' name='productid' maxlength='10' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>ProdDescr</td><td><input type='Text' id='proddescr' name='proddescr' maxlength='20' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type='Text' id='email' name='email' maxlength='100' value="aghuber11@gmail.com"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>LogNumber</td><td><input type='Text' id='LogNumber' name='LogNumber' maxlength='50' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Sender</td><td><input type='Text' id='sender' name='sender' maxlength='100' value="InboundProspect"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Sent To</td><td><input type='Text' id='sentto' name='sentto' maxlength='100' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Call Morning (Y/N)</td><td><input type='Text' id='callmorning' name='callmorning' maxlength='1' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Call Afternoon (Y/N)</td><td><input type='Text' id='callafternoon' name='callafternoon' maxlength='1' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Call Weekend (Y/N)</td><td><input type='Text' id='callevening' name='callevening' maxlength='1' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Call Evening (Y/N)</td><td><input type='Text' id='callweekend' name=callweekend' maxlength='1' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>ApptDate</td><td><input type='Text' id='ApptDate' name='ApptDate' maxlength='20' value="2016-12-01"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>ApptTime</td><td><input type='Text' id='ApptTime' name='ApptTime' maxlength='20' value="2pm"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>ProID</td><td><input type='Text' id='ProID' name='ProID' maxlength='5' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Srs-Sub ID#</td><td><input type='Text' id='srs_id' name='srs_id' maxlength='5' value=""></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Notes</td><td><input type='Text' id='notes' name='notes' maxlength='2000' value="this is a note"></td></tr>
   </table>
   <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>document.getElementById('form1').click();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're clicking the `form`, which doesn't do anything.  Either *submit* `form` or *click* the `button`.

Comment: `document.getElementById('form1').submit()`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be sending even with the .submit

Comment: Works here. Are you sure? Your action points to a "asp" page. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. That is the foreign server i'm trying to post onto. He isn't seeing any post data in his system. I tried just clicking the form myself and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use cURL in your case:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
    $data['firstname'] = (isset($_POST['firstname']))?$_POST['firstname']:'';
    $data['lastname'] = (isset($_POST['lastname']))?$_POST['lastname']:'';
    $data['$address1'] =(isset($_POST['address1']))? $_POST['address1']:'';
    $data['$city'] =(isset($_POST['city']))? $_POST['city']:'';
    $data['state'] = (isset($_POST['state']))?$_POST['state']:'';
    $data['zip'] = (isset($_POST['zip']))?$_POST['zip']:'';
    $data['phone'] =(isset($_POST['phone1']))? $_POST['phone1']:'';
    $data['email'] =(isset($_POST['email']))? $_POST['email']:'';
    $data['ApptDate'] = (isset($_POST['ApptDate']))?$_POST['ApptDate']:'';
    $data['ApptTime'] = (isset($_POST['ApptTime']))?$_POST['ApptTime']:'';
    $data['notes'] = (isset($_POST['notes']))?$_POST['notes']:'';
    $data['sender'] = (isset($_POST['sender']))?$_POST['sender']:'';

    $url = 'the_url_I_want_to_send_post_data';
    $c = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $response = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    var_dump($response); //just for debug, remove when in production
}
```

Comment: The page does work. It doesnt however auto submit when i hit the page with post vars from my node.js script. However if just visit the page with a query string it does work as intended

Comment: Your node.js script are rendering the PHP page into HTML in your browser? Or it is internal? Because if it is internal, the javascript will not be executed, neither the submit. You should use cURL instead.

Comment: Ok. It's internal. So i don't actually visit the page myself. Can you update your answer with an appropriate curl script please?

Comment: Edited.. try the new code. Just update the $url with the proper one.

Comment: If this is the solution, please mark this as the correct answer to help others with the same problem.

Comment: I will, I have to test it with the other developer to see if im getting results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer was correct. The problem was on the other end not mine ><.